# Firebase update result with PERMISSION_DENIED without breaking the rules - with solution

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I think it may be a bug in `update()` function with specific use of rules in Firebase.

I have following rules for `profile` node:

```
"profile": {
  "$appUserId": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "!newData.child('photo').exists()"
  }
}
```

*(I've omitted auth check in `.write` rule for clarity)*

User `profile` contains `photo` but it can be updated via back-end only. Client's can't set this information.

I'm using `update()` function to set profile data. When I create a profile (new node) everything is OK. But ones the profile is created each `update()` call results with PERMISSION_DENIED. It doesn't matter if I update one field or many in one call. Naturally, there were no `photo` key in incoming object. Also, `set()` function works perfectly in the same conditions (but removing any other fields - including `photo`).

When I remove `.write` rule (and just leave auth check) it's working. So I started wondering. For me, it looks like during the `update()` call it internally read existing data, merge it with incoming data overwriting old values with new ones and then it try to save it all. Before it actually save the data there is a rule check so - at this point - it will cause an error. I guess it should do rules check before data are merged (assuming that it works as I described above).

**Edit.**

To reproduce the problem:

1) Setup the code:

```
var appId = 'APP ID', appUserIdKey = 'test'; //appUserIdKey can be whatever you want

//data to be saved
var profileData = {
    name: "Pawel"
    age: 31,
    photo: 'image.jpg'
};
```

2) Since in my environment only the back-end saves data to `profile/[appUserIdKey]/photo` using service keys, you must temporarily remove `.write` rules.

Now rules should be like:

```
"profile": {
  "$appUserId": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "auth.uid !== null"
  }
}
```

3) run the code to create a profile

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://'+appId+'.firebaseio.com/profile/' + appUserIdKey); 
ref.update(profileData);
```

4) Now, restore the rules.

```
"profile": {
  "$appUserId": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "(auth.uid !== null) && (!newData.child('photo').exists())"
  }
}
```

5) Try to update profile again:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://'+appId+'.firebaseio.com/profile/' + appUserIdKey); 
ref.update({'age':18});
```

You'll receive an error

6) Change the rule to the following:

```
"profile": {
  "$appUserId": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "(auth.uid !== null) && (!newData.child('photo').exists()) || newData.child('photo').val() == data.child('photo').val())"
  }
}
```

It works now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Pawel. Can you include the minimal code to reproduce the problem? It's a bit hard to parse the description and seeing it as a code snippet will probably solve that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see my edit in the post.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. The behavior you're seeing matches the documentation. I added an answer with a quote from (and a link to) the relevant Firebase documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `newData`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/newdata.html) says:

> A RuleDataSnapshot corresponding to the data that will result if the write is allowed.

So it does not just contain the update, it contains the data as it will exist at the location if this write is allowed.

Comment: OK, now I see. And I see the logic standing behind it so change is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** for this issue is to extend the rule so it will return true if the old value is equal to new one:

```
"profile": {
  "$appUserId": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "(!newData.child('photo').exists() || newData.child('photo').val() == data.child('photo').val())"
  }
}
```

However, I think it shouldn't work like this and should be changed.